# React Hooks - useState using the result of another hook var set during useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Question: I am loading data from an API into my functional app component with useEffect (example below). I can't understand how to then set the variable `activeToken` because `phrases` is not yet defined, perhaps because useEffect is async?

What pattern should I be using to ensure that `phrases` exists before I invoke `activeToken`?

```
function App() {

  const getActiveToken = (tokens) => {
    for(let i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
      if (tokens[i].mask === true) {
        return i
      }
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/v1')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setPhrases(data))
  }
  )


  const [termIndex, setTermIndex] = useState(0);
  const [phrases, setPhrases] = useState([]);
  const [activeToken, setActiveToken] = useState(getActiveToken(phrases[termIndex].tokens))}
```

Comment: getActiveToken doesn't return anything and doesn't have a side effect, so what's it's purpose?

Comment: setPhrases is used before it is defined

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no issue of using an async function in a useEffect, since you are using then, not an await async function.

Comment: @BenCarp - getActiveToken just provides an index where the first .mask attribute in some of my data is true. It gets called later throughout the application but I don't think is fundamental to my problem.

Comment: If you can make your question a bit more clear I'd be happy to suggest an answer.

Comment: Does phrases change after component is mounted?

Comment: Phrases does change after the component is mounted. User actions modify the state.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set the initial state of `activeToken` from a state that you would update asynchronously (`phases`). Since `phases` is not ready when the component mounts, it won't be updated when `phases` changes, because the initial value is only used at the 1st render (`useState` initialization).

Since `activeToken` is derived from the `tokens`, which is derived from `phases`, you can compute it in the body of the component, and wrap it with `useMemo`, so it would only be computed when `tokens` change, but it's not strictly necessary unless `tokens` is huge. In addition the expression `phrases[termIndex].tokens` would throw an error, because `phrases[termIndex]` is `undefined`.

```
const getActiveToken = (tokens = []) => {
  for(let i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    if (tokens[i].mask === true) {
      return i
    }
  }
}

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/v1')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setPhrases(data))
  });   

  const [termIndex, setTermIndex] = useState(0);
  const [phrases, setPhrases] = useState([]);

  const tokens = phrases[termIndex]?.tokens;
  
  const activeToken = useMemo(() => getActiveToken(tokens), [tokens]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a seperate `async` function containing async code and call it in `useEffect`.

```js
//seperate function
const fetcher = async () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/v1')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setPhrases(data))
}

useEffect(() => {
   fetcher();
}
```

You can also

```js
useEffect(() => {
    //within useEffect
    let fetcher = async () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/v1')
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => setPhrases(data))
    }

    fetcher();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this dirction:
Try the following:

```js
function App() {

  const [activeToken, setActiveToken] = useState() // activeToken can't be set in the initial run anyway

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/v1')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((tokens) => {
        for(let i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        if (tokens[i].mask === true) {
          setActiveToken(tokens[i])
        }
      }



  })

}
```